# Compilation error when calling a Sub by a button click

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying execute this code when a button is pressed in the sheet,
but I receive this error :

> Call Worksheet_Change -> Compilation error - The argument is not optional

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Set MyPlage = Range("A1:I1200")
For Each cell In MyPlage
Select Case cell.Value
Case Is = "OK"
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
Case Is = "NOTOK"
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Case Is = "P"
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Case Else
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Select
Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Worksheet_Change
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you really want to process 10,800 cells every time you click a button?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Worksheet_Change sub - it has '(ByVal Target As Range)' as an argument. That means that when the worksheet changes, the sub triggers, and it carries the value of the range which changed. This allows you to manipulate the last edited cell, for example. In your command button, you aren't providing the Worksheet_Change sub with information about what Range you are referring to. As the error states, that argument is not optional.

However in your case, I can't see why you need to use the Worksheet_Change sub at all. I suggest you simply take the code currently within the top sub, and put it fully within the button's sub.

Answer (score 1):

The worksheet_change sub requires a range to be passed to it. Something like this should make it run:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call Worksheet_Change(Range("A1"))
End Sub
```

However putting this in the worksheet change event means that it triggers and runs every time anything in the sheet changes. The range value passed to the change event (A1 in my example above) is always the range of whatever cell/cells changed in the sheet.

If you want it to run ONLY when the button is pressed, name the sub something else and remove the 'byval target as range' argument to avoid having to pass a range to the sub. Something like:

```
Sub testSub()
Set MyPlage = Range("A1:I1200")
For Each cell In MyPlage
Select Case cell.Value
Case Is = "OK"
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
Case Is = "NOTOK"
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Case Is = "P"
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Case Else
cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
End Select
Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Call testSub
End Sub
```

If you want it to run any time the sheet is changed and also when the button is pressed, you're fine as you are, but I can't see that you're doing anything in your change sub that needs it to be in the worksheet change event?

Edit: Your problem is that you're looping through a range and undoing what you previously. Consider that this is your data:

```
__|_A__|_B_|___C___|__D__|_E_|_F_|_
1_|_OK_|___|_NOTOK_|_FOO_|_P_|___|_
2_|____|___|_______|_____|___|___|_
```

And for the purposes of this example (to keep it short) your MyPlage range is A1 to F2. Your loop is finding values and taking action like so:

```
A1 = OK > Colour whole row green
A2 = "" > Clear colour from whole row
B1 = "" > Clear colour from whole row (the row that was previously green)
B2 = "" > Clear colour from whole row
C1 = NOTOK > Colour whole row red (the row that was previously cleared of colour)
C2 = "" > Clear colour from whole row
D1 = "FOO" > Clear colour from whole row (the row that was previously red)
D2 = "" > Clear colour from whole row
E1 = "P" > Colour whole row yellow(the row that was previously cleared of colour)
E2 = "" > Clear colour from whole row
F1 = "" > Clear colour from whole row (the row that was previously yellow)
F2 = "" > Clear colour from whole row
```

Your end result is that all rows are cleared of colour as you're only taking the value in your last column as the input to determine row colour. So in your example, you'll only see a coloured row if your I column contains any of the values you're looking for.

You can see this in action by hitting F8 to step through the sub, or place a breakpoint on your celk.entirerow... elements so it stops when a case select is found to be true and then hitting F8 from there. I'd recommend trying it on a small data set first to see it in action or you'll have to hit F8 200 times to move across a column.

Comment: Unfortunately this code doesn't work for me. Colors doesn't change in the sheet. Can you test this code in your Excel ?

Comment: Updated the answer to explain why your code is coming out with no colours.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `Target` in `Worksheet_Change` sub, so you can pass any range to this sub like:

```
Call Worksheet_Change(Range("A1"))
```

or

```
Call Worksheet_Change(Range("B5000"))
```